How do I add Bulgarian spell check to MacBook M1 macOS Monterey?
I remember getting it to work somehow on my old MacBook but no such luck so far on this time around. I know I need .aff and/or .dic files but where do I get those?
Also when I add this to my MacBook, will it also transfer to my iPhone?
Are there any other solutions for this, even if paid and browser only?

In which applications do you wish to use the spellchecking? What have you tried so far?

@Alper for example notes, whatsapp. I am talking about the native macos spell check.

To find the .dic and .aff files you need, check the sites providing dictionaries for OpenOffice and its clones.  This page should help.
There is no way at present to add document spellcheck to iOS devices beyond what Apple or a 3rd party app like Word provides.

Sind you mentioned it could be browser only, I can personally recommend Microsoft Editor browser extension. With support over 20 languages including Bulgarian, it includes Grammar and Spelling checking. Works directly on the text you are working on. Best of all it is free. Example:


Thanks a lot! Have been looking for a good solution for browser for a long time!
